# React Native Conditional Rendering without if statement

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, rendering

Is it possible to re-render specific components without using if/else statement in the rendersection.
So when a specific statement changed only his specific component(s) will re-render 
while the rest remain intact.

Because if I use the componentWillUpdate or shouldComponentUpdate it will re-render the whole app scene again.

I look forward to your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like -

```
class MainComponent extends React.Component {
        displayMessage() {
            if (this.props.isGreeting) {
                return <Text> Hello, JSX! </Text>;
            } else {
                return <Text> Goodbye, JSX! </Text>;
            }
        }

        render() {
            return ( <View> { this.displayMessage() } </View> );
        }
    }
```

Check this article - https://medium.com/@szholdiyarov/conditional-rendering-in-react-native-286351816db4

Answer (score 1):

You can try with new ES6 enhanced object litrals.
We can access the property of an object using bracket `[]` notation:

```
myObj = { "name":"Stan", "age":26, "car": "Lamborghini"};
x = myObj["name"]; //x will contain Stan
```

So you can use this approach for conditional rendering

```
this.state = {
    contentToDisplay: "content1",
}

render() {
    return (
        <section>
            {{
                content1: <Content1 />,
                content2: <Content2 />,
                content3: <Content3 />,
            }[this.state.contentToDisplay]}
        </section>
    );
}
```